# position div in bootstrap

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

Wondering why it is so difficult to position divs to remain responsive.. they just float where ever they want for some reason.. how can I position these perfectly? Holding their positions while resizing like my social icons http://www.closetvip.com/splash.html

```
/* Menu Buttons */
#english {
    float:right;
    position:absolute;
    right:570px;
    bottom:101px;
    clear:right;

}
#spanish {
    position:absolute;
    left:570px;
    bottom:100px;
    clear:right;

}


<div id="spanish">
    <img src="img/espanol.png">
</div>
<div id="english">
    <img src="img/english.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `position: relative;` on the parent div of absolute div's otherwise the items are absolute of the window

Comment: sorry I dont follow? I have backstretch js for my background image?

Comment: Put your page into a container then style the container with position relative

Comment: container was put around english and spanish div, i put position relative nothing?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the use of bootstrap what so ever, only that it's inclued to the header and that is it...

You are position your element with fixed pixels on right/left and that is taken from the window border, so when you resize your window it's normal that the elements are pushed.

Your social icons are positioned with right 0 so it's normal to stay always at the right when you resize your window, but the 2 other buttons have 570px and they will always keep that space, so when you resize you know what is happening.

The Solution you ask?

You can position them with:

```
#spanish { bottom: 100px; clear: right; left: 50%; margin-left: -150px; position: absolute;} 
#english { bottom: 101px; clear: right; float: right; left: 50%; margin-left: 50px; position: absolute;}
```

Comment: Ok my mistake the margin should have been in pixels.


#spanish { bottom: 100px; clear: right; left: 50%; margin-left: -150px;  position: absolute;} 
#english {    bottom: 101px;    clear: right;    float: right;    left: 50%;    margin-left: 50px;    position: absolute;} I editted the answer.

Comment: again no luck ;( same problem occurs when resizing the window the divs float all the way up to the top I just want to keep the there.. I had tried to just use background image with Backstretch and do image map again no luck.. I am getting frustrated ready just to code this back like the ol days different spreadsheets :( :(

Comment: For the bottom if you can cut out the logo of the image and positioned it with the buttons it will be easier, since now it can't be done the way it is. The images tries to cover all of the space containing it's aspect ratio, so the buttons will be out of place.

Answer (score 0):

you have to control this by media queries or use % in your css rule 
like

```
#spanish {
    position:absolute;
    left:47%;
    bottom:20%;
    clear:right;

}
```

Note: this is not final just an example 
These are some standard media queries from chris coyier
[reference url](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1224px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1824px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 4 ----------- */
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
/* Styles */
}
```

use these and set position of your elements for all devices

Comment: I don't think I even understand this concept fully